# Removing subarray from array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array A and B.

```
A = [ 1, 2, 5, 9.8, 55, 3]
B = [ 3, 4]
```

Now, how to remove A[3] &  A[4]  that is whatever indices array B is having and then put them at the start of array A. 
So,  I want my output to be

```
A = [9.8, 55, 1, 2, 5,  3]
```

Note : Both A and B are numpy arrays.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

One approach with `boolean-indexing` would be -

```
mask = np.in1d(np.arange(A.size),B)
out = np.r_[A[mask], A[~mask]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [26]: A = np.array([ 1, 2, 5, 9.8, 55, 3])

In [27]: B = np.array([ 3, 4])

In [28]: mask = np.in1d(np.arange(A.size),B)

In [29]: np.r_[A[mask], A[~mask]]
Out[29]: array([  9.8,  55. ,   1. ,   2. ,   5. ,   3. ])
```

Another with integer-indexing -

```
idx = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(A.size),B)
out = np.r_[A[B], A[idx]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [36]: idx = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(A.size),B)

In [37]: np.r_[A[B], A[idx]]
Out[37]: array([  9.8,  55. ,   1. ,   2. ,   5. ,   3. ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-numpy answer.

```
A = [ 1, 2, 5, 9.8, 55, 3]
B = [ 3, 4]
new_arr = [A[i] for i in B if i<len(A)] + [A[i] for i in range(len(A)) if i not in set(B)]
# [9.8, 55, 1, 2, 5, 3]
```

You may remove the extra check `if i<len(A)` if you are sure about it.